# how to make shape in svg like the image attached?

Tags: svg, shapes, curve

how to make shape in svg like the image attached?

[image: Shape Image Click Here]

Comment: well, i guess you are going into wrong direction! look for SVG to create this kind of images not css!

Comment: How to make that shape programmatic? Or use a image editing program to make the shape? Which is it?